# MongoDB - Update field if new value is greater

Tags: mongodb

How to update a field in a MongoDB document only if the new value is greater then the current value?

Any solution?

```
db.report.update(
    { _id: 1234 },
    {
      $setIfGreater: {
        A: 10
      }
   })
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the [`$max`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/max/#up._S_max) operator to do this:

```
db.report.update(
    { _id: 1234 },
    {
      $inc: { A: 5 },
      $set: {
        B: "ABC123",
      }
      $max: {
        C: 10
      }
    })
```

> The `$max` operator updates the value of the field to a specified value
>   if the specified value is greater than the current value of the field.

Comment: How could I miss this? It goes to you as your answer come slightly earlier!

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [$max operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update/max/) and do something like:

```
db.report.update(
  { _id: 1234 },
  {
    $inc: { A: 5 },
    $set: {
      B: "ABC123",
    }
    $max: {
      C: 10
    }
}
```